# How do I call the function when a variable and function have a same name?

Tags: rust

A variable and function have the same name. How do I call the function?

```rust
fn main() {
    let a = 1;
    fn a() -> i32 {
        2
    }
    println!("{}", a());
}
```

The Rust compiler told me:

```
error[E0618]: expected function, found `{integer}`
```

In other words, the Rust compiler does not call the `a` function, but instead accesses the `a` variable.

Comment: I'll state the obvious solution: there's nothing *forcing* your variable to have the same name as the function. Change it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can't be done because you don't have both the function and the integer in scope where you have your `println`.

Because functions are normally available for the entire scope (i.e. you can use them before their declaration), their declaration is conceptually moved to the start of the scope (they're "hoisted").

A consequence is that the function declaration is before the integer variable declaration and is shadowed.

The real fix of your code would depend on your exact situation. Maybe something like this:

```
fn main() {
    {
        let a = 1;
        // use the integer there
    }
    fn a() -> i32 {
        2
    }
    println!("{}", a());
}
```

Comment: Reverse shadowing example to express the same idea: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=de828d843e285e4b355c95d7d95fda0c

Comment: Or, you know, not use the same name for two different objects.

Comment: Conceptually hoisted? Looks like a bug to me; scope should be in lexical order. EOF-y side up, not scrambled.

Comment: @Kaz In Rust you can call a function disregarding whether it was declared before or after the one in which you are. This isn't a bug, it's *very* convenient

Comment: @DenysSéguret In that case, all identifiers in that namespace should follow the same rule. What if I have a function-valued variable? It should be treated equally with the mix of functions in the same scope.